# 'No privilege' in PhpMyAdmin from xampp server

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I try to login as `username:root` and `password:''` , am unable to log into the PhpMyAdmin. When I entered `admin` as username and left the password field empty, I was able to login to the panel but `No Privilege` is displayed like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88w42.png) when I tried to create a database.

I checked the content in the `config.inc.php` file it is like this:

```
 /* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: you have an user named admin that has no password and to this user no privliges where assigned. You also have the root account with a password so if you try to login to phpmyadmin without it will fail. What is the question? Do you have clear that phpMyAdmin is a tool to access a mysql database server and not the server itself?

Comment: I need to know the password for the username `root`. I have checked the `config.inc.php` and the content were like above. But still am not able to login to `PhpMyAdmin` using the above credential.

Comment: You will never find the password for the root account of mysql in the config.inc.php file of phpMyAdmin. I am telling you that you are looking in the wrong place. For your phpMyAdmin configuration to work, just put here `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';` the password for the mysql root account. Even if I discourage you from storing that password in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you (or the XAMPP installer) has set a MySQL password. If you don't know what it is, you can reset it. https://serverfault.com/questions/4309/how-to-reset-or-recover-admin-account-password-for-mysql is a generic guide for any MySQL server, but looking at http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/01/how-to-change-the-root-password-for-mysql-in-xampp/ it appears as if XAMPP provides a means to set the password from http://localhost/security/ directly, so try that first.

The admin user working without privileges is simply the anonymous user, it's unlikely you actually have an "admin" account set up. The MySQL anonymous user will let you connect (but not have any real privileges) if the username (and/or host) doesn't match an existing user. You can disable the anonymous user if you wish once you regain control of your server.

I usually suggest using the auth_type cookie, in which case you don't need to hard code your username and password in the configuration file; you're prompted for that information when you log in.